# Calendar widget position in iframe on IE 7

Tags: iframe, dhtml

I have a web page that includes an iframe as well a DHTML calendar widget.  The page displays correctly as well as the content inside the iframe.  The problem is when I activate the calendar which is positioned close enough to the iframe that some of the calendar is hidden by the iframe.

I have tried to manipulate the positioning of the iframe by using both javascript and CSS (Zindex, z-index) but the iframe always appears as the top most layer on the page obscurring any parent DHTML content that gets rendered in the same area as the iframe.  I also changed the css of the DHTML calendar to values > 0 and wrapped the widget scriplet in a div/span with a high z-index value but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of an iframe is handled in [a](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/7718.htm) [weird](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro_drop8.html) [way](http://verens.com/archives/2005/07/15/ie-z-index-bug/) by IE. If you can get rid of it, I'd recommend you do and just embeded the content in a regular Div.

If you don't have other choices than do it like this, keep in mind that the z-index of elements like  and  will be infinite in IE6. So the way to stack that is to use iframes with higher zindexes, so that it will be infinity vs infinity+1.

An example of this is  vs  stacking. Both have infinite z-index, but you can stack them. [Checkout Stu Nicholls code](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro_drop8.html), that could be helpful.

That's pretty bad thought, my fix would be to avoid having other fields in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely cover the iFrame with a div.

The thing is you can't use z-index unless you use position:relative, or position:absolute, or position: fixed on the calandar div.

What you want to do is change the "position" CSS property of the calandar to be "relative".  If your iFrame has the normal static positioning (meaning you didn't add any special positioning to it, this will work).

If your iFrame has "absolute" positioning, you might need to do "position:absolute" on the calandar.

See link: http://resopollution.com/test/test.html

(works in all modern browsers including IE6)

Comment: "You can definitely cover the iFrame with a div." I doubt that will work in IE6.

Comment: Edited my post above with example link.  That works in IE6 and 7.

Comment: ok it works, I didn;t see the part about the absolute positioning. I doubt that having everything positionned absolute is good thing thought

Comment: Probably not.  Ideally the iFrame would have the default position:static, and the calandar would have position:relative or absolute.  If it's not working then probably you need to give position:relative to the top level parent of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "IE z-index bug" for a variety of examples and solutions to similar problems.  The html specification states that z-index should be absolute, but in IE it can be determined for an element if a parent element is positioned.  In extreme circumstances, I've had to trace back up the DOM tree from the element that's causing problems and set the z-index attribute on whatever parent element has position, not on the element that is being obscured (and should rightfully have its z-index set).  IE Developer toolbar can help for dynamic debugging if it's really a mess, just start setting the z-index properties up the tree until you find the one that makes it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the problem seems to be related to the MSXML and how IE transforms XML documents.  The XML has an XSLT stylesheet association which the browser uses to transform the XML document. The output of the transformation is an HTML document.  I didn't think it was import to disclose that I my HTTP response was XML since the HTML is what is rendered in the end, but it does matter.
When the source of the IFRAME is an HTML document everything works fine.  The DHTML is not covered by the IFRAME.  But when MSXML is used to transform the IFRAME content this is when the problem occurs.  Below are some sample files that illustrate the problem.
For the DHTML compoenent I am using the spiffycalendar widget but I would imagine any DHTML element would produce the same results.

**PARENT.HTML**

IFRAME DHTML CONFLICT EXAMPLE

```
                var pickupdate=new ctlSpiffyCalendarBox("pickupdate", "mainF", "PICKUP_DATE","btnDate1","",1);
            </script>
```

PARENT WINDOW


 








FIELD


FIELD


FIELDpickupdate.writeControl();


FIELD


FIELD


FIELD


Save Changes

**IFRAME.HTML**

**IFRAME.XSL**







]>

    
    
        
            
                TEST XML DOC
                
            
            
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                IFRAME CONTENT